# When does the forest end?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've been on this quest for about 20 minutes and it doesn't seem to have an end. I have 150,000 candies so far from killing the wolves, trees, etc. Am I just impatient? Another thing to note is that my screen is flooded with Octopus warriors - do they need to be out of the way for me to progress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have too many octopi. They'll be preventing you from moving right. I'm afraid you'll have to abandon your progress and restart, maybe without the obsidian crown? I find it easy to get through the forest with the jasper crown and enchanted monkey staff.

As a general rule, in *most* levels, if you can't see the background scrolling, you're not moving and the level won't progress. This is particularly relevant in the sea, where if you wedge yourself against the ground the waves of fish won't end.

Comment: The Black Magic Grimoire lets you cast Black Demons. The demons will kill some of the octopi, but they might also hurt you. Useful if you don't want to lose your progress and are willing to lose some health to finish the level.

Comment: I was able to use Jump (from the pogostick found in the mountains) to jump over the octi and reach the end

Answer (score 1):

yes your octopus warriors will stop you from walking forward, so youve been standing in place this whole time. either teleport out or start over. generally the obsidian crown is more burdemsome than useful

Answer (score 1):

Teleport yourself in order to past through the Octopus. Jump over them when you reach any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Octopus warriors block your further advance to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to jump over them. I've just tested it, and you can't squeeze past them, however, jumping seems to work just fine (may need desert bird's feather).

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are not wearing the boots of introspection. these will make is so you can not move at all. Though they look helpful, they really don't particularly help in combat.